# Optimizing Iterating over resultset php mysql with multi instances

Tags: php, optimization, mysqli

I am having a table that stores email that need to be send out. There is a cron script running that iterates over that table, gets the result set and sends out the email.

This is all well. However sometimes the cron might be called twice shortly after each other ( by user intervention).

The following happens
CRON
1- Fetch array of emails to be send out
2- Iterate in php over the resultset and send out the first email in the list
3- Remove the email from the table on successful sending.

However when at time nr 1 the cron is started by user intervention
there another fetch and send... so the email is send out twice.

Pseudo Code something like:

```
$results = query(Select * from EmailQueue);    // could contain 2000-5000 records
foreach(results)
{ 
  $res = DoSend();
  if ($res = true) {removeSentItemFromQueue();}    // only remove the email on successful send
}
```

What would be the best strategy for preventing it from sending twice, while keeping the code streamlined for speed.

Option 1: make the sql to get only 1 record, and place inside the loop ?
Option 2: transactions ?
Option 3: Get the record, set a semaphore that the code is working on it, so the next will only get non semaphore records.
Option 4 : ???
Option 5: ????

Your help and insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

- Add `status` field to `EmailQueue`
- When inserting email to send set the status to `pending`
- When retrieving `SELECT * EmailQueue WHERE status = 'pending'`
- If any found Update the table with status `sending`
- When sending the email if the result is `successful` you can delete
- if not set that record back to `pending` it will queued for the next cron task

Comment: Thank you... that is what I ment with sempahores. Any suggestions how that compares to other options in regards to speed ? as I need to now do a sql for every single item separately, and add another query to set the status for every item